# Installed windows 10 over ubuntu 16.04 and getting error while installing grub using live usb of ubuntu?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, uefi

So i had my laptop with ubuntu 16.04 installed as a single OS in **legacy** mode and it worked fine . Now i tried dual booting it with windows 10 over Ubuntu 16.04 but i installed windows 10 in **UEFI** mode instead of ***legacy*** mode thinking it would enable more features for windows .

Now the windows 10 is working fine but as i try to reinstall or fix my **grub** using these commands on this link ***" goo.gl/EYtB5J "*** using the terminal on a live usb ubuntu 16.04 (the live usb works only in UEFI mode , i don't know why ) . So as i mount my ubuntu installed partition , all proceeds successfully but as soon as i try **"grub-install /dev/sda"** in the root i encounter this error ***"grub-install: error: cannot find EFI directory."***

So the thing is i cannot boot into my Ubuntu OS installed in its respective partition until i reinstall grub using a live usb which i am not able to fix . So if can anyone help me with this i'd really appreciate it (coz i've spent more than 12 hours over the span of 2 days trying to fix this problem) ?

Also if i install UBUNTU 16.04 again using that live usb over the previously installed UBUNTU 16.04's partition , would it create a problem if i follow the standard procedure ? Should i be careful about anything particular while doing this ?

Comment: Option 1. Change boot mode to Legacy to boot to Ubuntu.. UEFI to boot to Windows. Option 2 reinstall Ubuntu in UEFI mode on same partition to dual boot Windows and Ubuntu with out any problem.. If I am U, I choose Option 2

Comment: I thought exactly the same as you said about option 1 but the thing is even when i am booting in legacy mode , i get booted into the Windows 10 OS only for some reason i don't know why !
I guess option 2 will be the most feasible considering the situation i am stuck in currently and seeing no solutions posted to my original problem , So are you sure Pratap that its perfectly safe to reinstall Ubuntu in UEFI mode on same partition ?

Comment: Yes i am sure, the reason for 1st option failed in your case, may be you tried to reinstall grub on it.. If you want to 1st option to avail, boot in Legacy mode and repair the grub.

Comment: Thanks a Lot @PRATAP , really appreaciate your help . 
But the thing is when i try to boot in legacy mode without live USB , it gets booted into windows 10 (even though i installed it in UEFI mode) .
Also when i try to boot into **live USB** in legacy mode , the following error occurs . 

"Failed to open \EFI\BOOT\mmx64.efi - Not Found "
'Failled to load image \EFI\BOOT\mmx64.efi: Not Found'
"Failed to start MokManager: Not Found "

while the live USB works perfectly fine in UEFI mode for some reason.

Comment: the error is due to you tried to repair or reinstall grub considering EFI and corrupted.. if you did not tried repair or reinstall, 100% it works Legacy willl take you to Ubuntu, UEFI takes you to Windows 10.. can you share your laptop model or mother board..

Comment: the live USB how did you create? with Rufus?

Comment: I am using Acer Travelmate P259 series , model no : N16Q2.
yeah i tried to install grub using the commands i found on the link i shared in my question description that is the command "grub-install /dev/sda" . So what do you think i should do now ?

and NO i created live USB using **Startup Disk Creator**

Comment: in quick, proceed with Option 2. in delay let me see the model details and capabilities..

Comment: i could not get the required details from the manual to see why it even booted when its in legacy mode to windows10. anyway reinstall Ubuntu on same partition in UEFI mode to full stop all the errors and dual boot happily.

Comment: Thanks a lot @PRATAP . i'll do it then . I didn't know that we can read manuals as well to get information regarding booting stuff related to ubuntu or something . Thanks once again . I'll reinstall the ubuntu then using the live USB in UEFI mode then .